# WPF App - AzureAD Audience validation failed

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory

So I'm stuck...

I have a simple api running on Azure. It has AzureAD configured according to company policy.
I can access the api via my browser fine. Also tried postman to access which also works fine with the following settings:

Type: OAuth 2.0

```
Grant Type: Implicit
Callback URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
Auth URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/authorize?resource={{client_id}}
Client ID: {{client_id}}
Scope: api://{{client_id}}/gh_client_access
```

Now I'm trying to access via a WPF app using the same settings. I'm using MSAL.
In my app I configured the following:

```
static App()
{
    _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
        .WithB2CAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}/oauth2/authorize?resource={ClientId}")
        .WithTenantId(Tenant)
        .WithClientId(ClientId)
        .Build();
}
```

in the window I'm getting a token:

```
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

I receive a token, but when making a request I get the error:

```
{"code":401,"message":"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'."}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using B2C authentication? The format should be `.WithB2CAuthority("https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}/{PolicySignInSignUp}")`. Please have a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, Sorry was very busy at work, I'm going to try and see if this fixes it today and will report back in.

Comment: May I know which idp you are using? Azure AD or Azure AD B2C?

Comment: If you are using AAD, you should use `WithAuthority()` method rather than `WithB2CAuthority()`. Like `.WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}/oauth2/authorize")`

Comment: I actually think you're right, I should use WithAuthority(), (I actually tried a lot of different things already), but I still get the audience error. As I mentioned, in postman everything is working fine somehow

Comment: Please decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see what the `aud` is.

Comment: The audience is set to "api://{Application (client) ID}"

Comment: It's fixed! decoding the access token in jwt.io really helped, thanks a lot @AllenWu. It was my scope that wasn't in the correct format. instead of api://{ClientID} it should've just been the ClientID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this answer here in case anyone else has the same issue.

First mistake, B2C Authority while I needed regular Azure AD:

```
static App()
{
    _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
        .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}")
        .Build();
}
```

Now the other problem was in the scope. This defines the audience and was in the wrong format.
Where I had `api://{client_id}/{scope_name}` it had to be `{client_id}/{scope_name}`.

If you have the same situation where postman is working, have a look at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and decode your working token and your erroneous token to compare.

Thanks to @AllenWu for helping out!